# bash equivalent of this use of tcsh "sched" command?

Tags: bash, tcsh, shell-builtin

In tcsh, the built-in `sched` command causes a command to be executed by the current shell at a specified time.

I have the following `$HOME/.sched` file (this is a simplified version of it):

```
setenv today `date +%F`
sched +00:01 sched 00:00 source $HOME/.sched
```

I then `source $HOME/.sched` in my `$HOME/.cshrc`.

This sets the environment variable `$today` to, for example, `"2012-06-25"`, and automatically updates it to the current date every night at midnight. The job automatically reschedules itself every time it runs.

Note that the `date` command is invoked only once each day, and only when it's needed.

Is there a way to do this in bash? Note that the `at` command won't work; it invokes a command externally and cannot affect the current shell's environment.

(I know that I can type `$(date +%F)` rather than `$today`, but since I use this interactively, the extra typing is a significant burden.)

tcsh also has a number of special aliases that are executed automatically in certain circumstances:

> The *beepcmd*, *cwdcmd*, *periodic*, *precmd*, *postcmd*, and *jobcmd* **Special
>   aliases** can be set, respectively, to execute commands when the shell
>   wants to ring the bell, when the working directory changes, every
>   **tperiod** minutes, before each prompt, before each command gets
>   executed, after each command gets executed, and when a job is started
>   or is brought into the foreground.

Does bash have anything like these?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `$PROMPT_COMMAND` ?
It is commonly used to set the xterm title to show CWD for example.
It is executed when the prompt is shown. It may be possible to set your variable with this. The first disadvantage would be that your command will be executed everytime you press enter in the shell. The second would be that if are not active on your terminal for long time and the day passes, it will not get automatically set. It will get set after next enter on terminal.

```
# export PROMPT_COMMAND="export today=\`date\`"
# echo $today
Tue Jun 26 01:07:19 EEST 2012
# echo $today
Tue Jun 26 01:07:21 EEST 2012
# echo $today
Tue Jun 26 01:07:22 EEST 2012
```

Comment: That's likely to be the best I can do. The first disadvantage is what I'm most concerned about. We'll see of anyone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: unfortunately bash does not have a pre-command (if we consider `$PROMPT_COMMAND` as a post-command).

Comment: Pre- vs. post- doesn't matter much; I can live with `$today` not being set correctly for the first command I execute after midnight.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing trade two backquotes for a dollar:

```
alias today='date +%F'
echo `today`
```

If you want the date in a variable, then [updating it in `PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41619/bash-equivalent-of-this-use-of-tcsh-sched-command/41620#41620) is the only way I can think of. You can avoid forking a process at each prompt by using the built-in variable `SECONDS`.

```
update_today () {
  if ((SECONDS/86400 > __last_today_update)); then
    ((__last_today_update = SECONDS/86400))
    today=$(date +%F)
  fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND="update_today; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Another approach is to insert your text through a key binding.

```
rl_insert () {
  READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE:0:$READLINE_POINT}$1${READLINE_LINE:$READLINE_POINT}
  ((READLINE_POINT+=${#1}))
}
bind -x '"\C-xt":rl_insert "$(date +%F)"'
```

Comment: the readline approach is interesting, thanks for sharing.

Comment: The expression `((SECONDS/86400))` will change at 24-hour intervals after the shell started, not at midnight; `/` is truncating integer division (and `$SECONDS` is the number of seconds since the shell started).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for `at`:

```
~$ at now + 1 minute
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "test" | wall
at> 
job 2 at Mon Jun 25 17:51:00 2012

Broadcast Message from user@host                                              
        (somewhere) at 17:51 ...                                               

test
```

Though, I just reread your question, and you're looking for something that will re-self-schedule itself.  That'd be pretty easy to do with `at` calling a shell script that does what it needs to do and then sets up a new `at` job.   However, `at` does run in its own subshell; not as the shell you invoke it from.

Comment: As I said in the question, `at` won't work; it can't set an environment variable in the shell from which it's invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like bash has an equivalent feature, at least not with all of the qualities you describe. If you're looking for a "best of both worlds", **zsh** has `sched` features.

I do realize that might be just as unhelpful as the other answers though.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea for a solution:

```
$ trap 'today=$(date)' 10
$ echo $today
$ sleep 8
$ kill -10 $$
$ echo $today
```

Now you can use at to send yourself ($$) a signal at the turn of the day.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution that works without firing off an extra process on every prompt. Like [0xAF's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/41620/10454), it uses `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. It's a bit convoluted, but it seems to work.

There are three steps:

First, I created a script called `update-dot-today`. I put it in `$HOME/bin`.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$HOME/.today
mkdir -p $dir
file_count=$(ls $dir | wc -l)
today=$(date +%F)

if [ $file_count -eq 1 ] ; then
    if [ ! -e $dir/$today ] ; then
        mv $dir/* $dir/$today
    fi
else
    mv $dir $dir-$$
    mkdir -p $dir
    touch $dir/$today
    rm -rf $dir-$$
fi
```

When this is run, it ensures that the file `$HOME/.today/YYYY-MM-DD` exists, and that nothing else exists under `$HOME/.today`. Once the file is created, the script will just rename the existing file as needed, avoiding any race conditions.

Second, I added two entries to my crontab:

```
@reboot         $HOME/bin/update-dot-today
0 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/update-dot-today
```

This ensures that the file is created on boot and updated every night at midnight local time.

Third, I added the following to my `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
today=$(date +%F)
if [ -d $HOME/.today ] ; then
    PROMPT_COMMAND='if [ ! -f "$HOME/.today/$today" ] ; then today=$(ls $HOME/.today) ; fi'
fi
```

This checks for the appropriate `$HOME/.today/YYYY-MM-DD` file -- but if it already exists and its name matches the current value of `$today`, the only cost is a file existence check.

If you prefer, the `YYYY-MM-DD` file can be placed somewhere other than `/tmp/today`, perhaps under your home directory. (In fact that might be safer, in case something cleans up `/tmp` between reboots, or in case another user on the system uses the same approach).

The only drawback (apart from the fact that it's rather complicated) is that the value of `$today` is set only after a shell prompt is printed. But that's just a matter of remembering to type an extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> at least once after midnight.

Comment: I think I have a better solution that doesn't require using `crontab`. I'll update this answer (and delete this comment) once I've verified that it actually works.